# Will Gauss quadrature numerical integration work with a variable dx

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The question kind of says it all, but I'm reading about Gauss quadrature from here: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/lectures/nummeth98/integration.htm

which gives an equation of this form:
[image]

and it's not clear to me whether I would get the same results with a fixed $\Delta x$ as one that varied. For example let's say that I evaluate at $x_i=10^k$ where $k=0,0.1,0.2,0.3$ etc. and take $\Delta x_i = x_{i+1} - x_i$.

And if it does still work, will it increase the error markedly?

Comment: Imagine that we will do a fixed number $K$ of function evaluations. For "nice" functions, one can get very much more precision from a weighted sum, at judiciously selected non-uniformly distributed points (as in Gaussian quadrature) than from a weighted sum at $K$ evenly distributed points.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I may have misunderstood your comment, but I'm not sure it addresses my question, I know Gauss quadrature gives more precision by using non-uniformly distributed points. My question is whether the points we centre these around (the x0s in the equation) need to vary uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the formula that you quote is a local error inside one interval and does not depend on the other intervals in any way, in particular not on how uniform they are. So the intervals might be nonuniform and perhaps concentrated in regions where f is badly-behaved. The error that you quote as $\cal{O}(\Delta x^4)
$ can be shown to be, more precisely but still approximately,
$$C\frac{\partial^4f}{\partial x^4}\Delta x^4$$
where C is a pure number associated with the quadrature rule employed. A possible strategy would be to make the absolute value of this quantity about the same in every interval. This is called adaptive quadrature. It becomes almost essential in large domains in higher dimensions. However, if you just change the intervals on some arbitrary whim, it probably will reduce the accuracy.